# Is there any way to redirect output from smbclient?

Tags: smb

I know that smbclient does not allow output redirection but is there any workaround for this to get the output to either text file or std?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:

```
$ smbclient -U USER%PASSWORD //IPTOSHARE/DIRECTORY/ -c 'cd ANOTHERDIR; dir' > sampletext.txt
```

Comment: Just a recommendation: don't hardcode or put passwords in commands; this goes into history and all sorts of bad things can happen. Strongly suggest putting the password in a file, and then shredding the file and changing the password (particularly when the command supports stored credentials). Just my $0.01.